# Embed Custom SQL with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

From what I have looked at so far, I am guessing the answer to this question is "no" but I thought I would ask in the event that I am missing something.

I have looked at the new RLS (row-level security) feature of Azure SQL.  One of the things that needs to be done is to set the (user) context before executing a SQL statement.  Since I am also looking at entity framework, my question is whether or not I can *embed* or *inject* something like "EXECUTE AS USER = 'User1'" into the SQL that is generated by entity framework.

Is this something that is possible?  I know I can execute custom SQL but I was looking to set the code up in one place and have it run the statement for all generated SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this [EF6 feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) can help, and more particularly the [interception interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) by the  IDbCommandInterceptor.

Not clear about the hability to change the generated sql but may be.

Otherwise, have you tried a `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXECUTE AS...")` ?

Comment: It seems like I read about this some time ago and decided that I would not ever need it.  This feature seems a bit *clunky*.  I marked your solution as the answer as it solves the issue, regardless of how *clunky* it may be.

Comment: I must admit I agree with you: this is not light at all.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new connectionstring using the user if you need to, or, you can modify the connectionstring used by DbContext.